# Can any one help me in drawing a bar graph...?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-graphics

In my application I have to read data from a file or core data and draw a bar graph using that data.  Can any one help me in drawing the bar graph in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) library successfully. Here are some basic tutorials, but you will have to adjust to suit your particular scenario:

[Using Core Plot in an iPhone Application](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application)

[High Level Design Overview](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/HighLevelDesignOverview)

[Visualizing Data with Core Plot](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/26/p973)

Comment: Thank you ver much dude this helped me alot...


~Raviraja

Answer (score 1):

check out this:
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/